# Adding comma after city in a cell with City State Zip

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am having trouble adding a comma after the city in a column with City State Zip.

**Example:**

New Bern NC 27856

Wilson NC 27866

**Desired Result:**

New Bern, NC 27856

Wilson, NC 27866

I am struggling because some cities are more than one word, so I cant use a substitute function. Also, text to columns is a mess when trying to manipulate city, state zip.

Any suggestions?

THANK YOU!

Comment: If it's always the word before two capital letters perhaps exploit that.

Comment: Right. So I attempted to use an IF(LEN function but ended up making a mess. I am new to Excel formulas but am getting the hang of certain things. But, this is exactly what I am trying to do. If two letters in general. The state will always be two letters.

Comment: Can you post what you've tried please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried this and it worked fine:

```
=LINKS(B2;LENGTE(B2) - 7) & "," & RECHTS(B2;LENGTE(B2) - 7)
```

Obviously, you'll need to translate from Dutch to English commands:

```
LINKS() => LEFT()
LENGTE() => LENGTH()
RECHTS() => RIGHT()
```

The whole formula is based on the idea that you need the last 7 characters "XX YYYY" where "XX" is "NC" in your case, and "YYYY" is the postal code.

Comment: Translated to =LEFT(Y2,LEN(Y2) - 7) & "," & RIGHT(Y2,LEN(Y2) - 7)

Comment: I get New Burn N,n NC 27856 and Wilson N,NC 27866 -- I like your thinking thought. Instead of 7 it is 9. We forgot the spaces count. But even then it does double word cities well, but messes up single word cities.

Comment: `=LEFT(A10,LEN(A10)-9)&","&RIGHT(A10,9)`

Comment: Yes PB that worked. Amazing. I can't wait to be able to write these out myself. I spend more time trying to figure it out. I am taking courses right now.